# ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: <class 'RecursionError'>: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I'm new to python. I'm trying to make a Sign-up/Log-in sistem in python using Kivy for the GUI. My code works like a charm when it comes to a single .py file but, when I call (with `import Login`) another .py script, everything falls apart.

**This is my Register.py file:**

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder

db = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
                     user="user",
                     passwd="password",
                     db="database",)

mycursor = db.cursor()

Builder.load_file("Stuff.kv")

condse = "@", "mail", ".",

class Stuff(Widget):

    def register(self):

        email = (self.ids.email.text)

        pw = (self.ids.password.text)

        mycursor.execute("select count(*) from email_password where email = %s", (email,))

        result = mycursor.fetchone()[0]

        if result < 1:
            if len(email) > 1:
                if all(condse in email for condse in condse):

                        if not pw.islower() and not pw.isupper() or pw.isupper():

                            Acc = email, pw

                            Form = "INSERT INTO email_password (email, password) VALUES (%s, %s)"

                            mycursor.execute(Form, Acc)

                            db.commit()

                            import Login           #<-----------THIS IS THE PROBLEMATIC IMPORT



    def quit(self):
        Register().stop()

class Register(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.size = (1920, 1080)
        Window.fullscreen = False
        return Stuff()

Register().run()
```

**Minimal Register.py file**

```
class Stuff(Widget):
    def register(self):
        import Login  #<-------- Problematic Import
    

class Register(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.size = (1920, 1080)
        Window.fullscreen = False
        return Stuff()

Register().run()
```

**This is my Login.py file:**

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder


db = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
                     user="user",
                     passwd="password",
                     db="database",)

mycursor = db.cursor()

Builder.load_file("Stuff1.kv")

condse = "@", "mail", ".",



class Stuff1(Widget):

    def login(self):

        email1 = (self.ids.email.text)

        pw1 = (self.ids.password.text)

        mycursor.execute("select count(*) from email_password where email = %s", (email1,))

        result = mycursor.fetchone()[0]

        if result > 1 and len(email1) > 1:

            if not pw1.islower() and not pw1.isupper() or pw1.isupper() and len(pw1) > 8:

                Acc = email1, pw1

                Form = "INSERT INTO email_password (email, password) VALUES (%s, %s)"

                mycursor.execute(Form, Acc)
            else:
                print("The password must contain 8 characters and at least 1 capital letter")
        else:
            pass

    def quit(self):
        Login().stop()


class Login(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.size = (1920, 1080)
        Window.fullscreen = False
        return Stuff1()


Login().run()

db.commit()
```

**Minimal Login.py**

```
class Stuff1(Widget):

    def login(self):
    def quit(self):  #this is a button function that i use to quit (not very important, it's just to tell you what it does)
        Login().stop()


class Login(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.size = (1920, 1080)
        Window.fullscreen = False
        return Stuff1()


Login().run()
```

When i click the "Submit" button **(`def register(self):`)** it should close the "Register" script and open the "Login" one but, instead, it crashes and spams this error in the run console:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Mattia Antonacci\Desktop\Robe\RipetraMySql\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\input\providers\wm_pen.py", line 74, in _pen_wndProc
     return windll.user32.CallWindowProcW(self.old_windProc,
 ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: <class 'RecursionError'>: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I hope someone can help me...

Comment: Why are you importing there? what is in "Login.py"?

Comment: @TomMyddeltyn I'm importing there because I want "Login.py" to be imported as soon as i click the button (`def register(self):` is the function of the button). In "Login.py" there is pretty much the same stuff. I just want to import "Login.py" as soon as i press the button.

Comment: Does `import Login` always break? Or is it irrelevant for this example? Could you try posting a [mre]?

Comment: @RandomDavis yes it always breaks. I will do it right now.

Comment: This is not a normal use case of import and is going to cause you a bunch of headaches. I'd recommend putting the code you want to run here in a function inside of Login.py (say call it `def login():` and then `import Login` at the top with the rest of your imports then call `Login.login()` where you were importing.

Comment: @TomMyddeltyn I think i don't understand what you're trying to say me..

Comment: Also, realize that the import will only happen one time and not each time you call the function. It really shouldn't be used to run the code inside of a python script.

Comment: @TomMyddeltyn thanks for posting a [mre], although it's not actually reproduceable if you didn't include `Login`. Unless its contents are irrelevant? An MRE should be something we can just paste into an IDE essentially.

Comment: @MattiaAntonacci What I mean is that when you call import, it is not exactly like running the code in that script file. I'm assuming that Login.py is the issue.

Comment: @TomMyddeltyn Ok, I'm going to post the Login.py too.

Comment: Your Minimal reproducible example doesn't work as is. It should be able to run. I think we'd need the kv file

Answer (score 0):

From your minimal examples, I think this should fix your issue.
When you import, it brings the code in typically *once* it doesn't 'reload' the file each time. Running a python script from another python script typically you'll want the executable code to be in functions and call them as `module.function()`.

Also, you'll want to put the "main" executable code into an `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement. This allows the file to be both run like `python foo.py` and imported like `import foo` Otherwise, when you `import foo` all the code will be executed that one time. Note that even when multiple places import the same library it typically is only imported really once.

```
import Login

class Stuff(Widget):
    def register(self):
        #import Login  #<-------- Problematic Import
        Login.Login().run()
    

class Register(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.size = (1920, 1080)
        Window.fullscreen = False
        return Stuff()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Register().run()
```

Login.py

```
class Stuff1(Widget):

    def login(self):
        pass
    def quit(self):  #this is a button function that i use to quit (not very important, it's just to tell you what it does)
        Login().stop()


class Login(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.size = (1920, 1080)
        Window.fullscreen = False
        return Stuff1()

#This makes it so the code ONLY runs when 
# this is the script is called from python vs. import.
# i.e. python Login.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Login().run()
```

Comment: I added everything, but it spams this error in the run console: `ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: <class 'RecursionError'>: maximum recursion depth exceeded in __instancecheck__`